# How to slicing array interface in system verliog

Tags: system-verilog

I try to use array interface mapping through always_comb procedure instead of generate a statement.

You can see my test codes is in below(https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5cLt)

```
interface tintf;
  bit   valid;
  bit   data;
  bit   stall; 

endinterface: tintf

module top;
  tintf intf_a[0:3]();
  bit valid, data, stall;

  always_comb begin
    loop_for_mapping:
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
      intf_a[i].valid = valid;
      intf_a[i].data = data;
    end
  end  
endmodule
```

But I see the error message below.

> intf_a[i].valid = valid;
>    | ncelab: *E,NOTPAR (./testbench.sv,18|13): Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].

I don't know that is why illegal...As I know 'i' in for-loop is considered constant.

Would you let me know what I missing??

Answer (score 2):

It may be true for synthesis the for loop gets unrolled into a constant set of iterations, but it's not a constant from a language point of view. Simulation tools don't know which portions of your code you plan to synthesize. You need to write this as a `generate-for` loop.

```
for(genvar i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin : loop_for_mapping
  always_comb begin
    intf_a[i].valid = valid;
    intf_a[i].data = data;
  end
end
```

Comment: You means there is no-way avoid using "generate-for" in this case....
    Thank you^^

Comment: Correct. Arrays of instances are not true arrays and have to be handled specially. True arrays of data just need a memory offset to index into each element.

Answer (score 0):

instantiating an interface (or a module) as an array  (*arrayed instance*)  is a part of the `generate` feature of verilog. As a result, you can only access those by using literal constants (0,1,2...) or from other generate blocks (see dave_59's answer).

It can be more flexible if you make arrays of the interface variables instead:

```
interface tintf;
  bit   [3:0] valid;
  bit   [3:0] data;
  bit   [3:0] stall; 

endinterface: tintf

module top;
  tintf intf_a();
  bit valid, data, stall;

  always_comb begin
    loop_for_mapping:
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
      intf_a.valid[i] = valid;
      intf_a.data[i]= data;
    end
  end  
endmodule
```